# AVD screen is transparent and unclickable

Tags: android-studio

The AVD main screen of my Android Studio became transparent and unclickable (as shown in the first picture). I can be sure that the emulator is started normally at this time, because it shows a little bit of ToolBar color (purple) at the top. I've tried deleting the device and creating a new one, but the new device is still transparent. The version of my Android Studio is as follows (second picture)

[image]

[image]

I've tried deleting the device and creating a new one, but the new device is still transparent.
I also tried restarting Android studio or restarting my computer

Comment: After I changed the version of Android Studio from Flamingo to Giraffe, AVD can be used normally